# Server 2019 Rsc performance issues, mitigated by moving the VM

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2019, hyper-v-server-2019

we recently discovered that Rsc (Receive segment coalescing) has been affecting the performance of our software when running on 2019 VM's on our new 2019 Hyper V host.

We have found that turning off Rsc on the Virtual Switch does fix the performance issues, however, before we discovered this issue we noticed that if we moved the VM from our 2019 Host to one of our older hosts and back, the issue appeared to be resolved, at least temporarily.

Is there a reason why moving a VM from one host to another would affect the way in which Rsc works?